# Cost of using AGPS for satellite location

Tags: gps

Can anyone tell me, if I want to use GPS or AGPS with an app to locate a satellite for TV reception, will I be charged for the data. I'm thinking of buying a Huawei g300 Pay as you go from Vodaphone but don't want to be landed with heavy charges to use this facility while abroad. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assisted GPS may cost money: it depends on your cellphone provider, and you should check with them first. See [this old CNET story](http://www.cnet.com.au/watch-out-for-data-charges-on-your-gps-phone-339281483.htm) for more info. For Vodafone, I couldn't find any official information online, but [this thread by a user on the official forum](http://forum.vodafone.co.uk/t5/Windows-Phone/A-GPS/td-p/1269092) suggests they charge A-GPS data the same as any other Internet access.

If you're worried about the data charges, go into **Settings** -> **Wireless and networks** -> **Mobile networks**, and turn off **Data roaming** (the names may be slightly different depending on which device and Android version you have). While data roaming is turned off, your phone won't try to use mobile data while you're roaming (that is, abroad). The GPS will still work fine, but it may take longer to fix your position: maybe as long as 12 minutes, [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS).

Whether the app you want to use will still work without an internet connection depends on the app you're trying to use. You should probably test this before getting abroad: if it turns out you have to download and use a different app, you won't have saved any money at all!